# PHP form update mysql database not completing updates

Tags: php, mysql, database, edit

so I have been tinkering around with mysql database update function for my invoice management system for work, but I cant seem to get it to actually edit the records in my mysql database for an unknown reason. Here is my code for my edit.php page

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "password");
if (!$con) {
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("inventory",$con);

if (isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE invoice SET Inv #='$_POST[inv_number]', Date Type='$_POST[date_type]', ID='$_POST[id]' WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";               
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
};

$sql = "SELECT * FROM invoice";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Inv #</th>
<th>Date Type</th>
<th>ID</th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<form action=edit.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=inv_number value=" . $record['inv_number'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=date_type value=" . $record['date_type'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=id value=" . $record['id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
}

echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

This is the button I have on my search.php page where my records are being shown.

```
<a href='edit.php?edit=$row[id]'>edit</a>
```

Upon entering the edit.php page when i click on my edit button for a specific record, it shows all the records in my table, which is not ideal as I would much rather see only the record that I want to edit/update. These two problems are a problem that I have been unable to solve. Any help is appreciated. Thx in advance everyone.

Comment: Your `SELECT` statement doesn't have a `WHERE` clause, so it's pulling all the rows from your `invoice` table. Your php code's `while` loop is dutifully rendering them all. Please try adding a `WHERE` clause and let us know what happens.

Comment: Well, with that glaring SQL injection vulnerability I doubt you'll have to worry too long about having so many records in the database anyway.  You'll likely want to start reading here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: added this  $sql = "SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE id='$id'";  But the edit form fields dissappered

Comment: actually this code will never see the internet. its for personal use only on a computer that is purposely unable to connect to internet

Comment: Sidenote: Consider quoting this `<form action=edit.php method=post>` - `<form action='edit.php' method='post'>` - you should also do `<form><table></table></form>` instead, as a broken down example. Plus `name='inv_number'` etc. those quotes can be important.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: ah yes thank you fred, but still not editing records unfortunately

Comment: You're missing a `>` for `<input type=submit name=update value=update` so do `<input type=submit name=update value=update>` probably why it's not working. Plus backticks around `Inv #`

Comment: Matter 'o fact, you're missing `>` for all your inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your MySQL column name really Inv #? If so, you need to add backticks like this:

```
`Inv #`
```

But looking at your form, it looks like the field name is inv_number. Also, you are seeing all records because your select clause does not have a where modifier.

Comment: yes yes, after I changed the names Inv # and Date Type and ID to inv_number date_type and id  it finally worked. and i included the backticks as well. Great!

Comment: but I am still having trouble selecting one record for editing, after clicking even with this WHERE statement ... $sql = "SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE id='$id'";

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM invoice";
```

with this line

```
    $where = '';
    if(!empty($_GET) && !empty($_GET['edit'])) {
        $where = ' where id='.$_GET['edit'];
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM invoice".$where;
```

Comment: it worked great, one small detail however, after clicking update it added a second record in the table for editing, can we prevent that from happening?

Comment: actually it adds all the existing records in the database, i thought only one because i only had 2 test records in my database

Comment: can you tell me that what is the structure of the table ?